# How can I escape double quotes in sed command using args and echo command?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, escaping, echo

I am working on a bash script, trying to find a regexp in a file, substitute (with sed) a part of regexp corresponding to a float number by this number divided by 2.

Example:

```
echo set NEX \"2.00\" > testfile
cat testfile
```

Output:

```
set NEX "2.00"
```

Command:

```
sed -i -r 's/(set NEX ")([0-9.]+)(")/echo \1$(echo "scale=2;\2\/2" | bc)\3/e' testfile
cat testfile
```

Output:

```
set NEX 1.00
```

So, my problem is that echo in sed command seems not to escape and interpret the double quote returned by \1 and \3. I tried many escaping tricks like using \ or '"'"' but it still does not work.
I will be happy to have some help and to learn more about bash, my studies in shell are far behind me :)

Thank you in advance!

zet

Comment: `the double quote returned by \1 and \3` When you write _in your terminal_ : `echo set NEX "$(echo something)"` do that `"` show up _in the output_?

Comment: @KamilCuk, it returns: Illegal variable name.

Comment: `e` is calling the shell, which will interpret quotes as a shell does.  So, just add a sed command that adds the quotes back.  `s/\b[.0-9]\+\b/"&"/` maybe.

Comment: thank you, it works in a way with `s/[0-9.]+/"&"/` but the problem is that I need to substitute only the line in the file with a  `set NEX "`.
Btw, what does `\b` stand for? and why do you escape the `+`?
Tyvm anyway

Comment: Enclose in `/set NEX/{}` ... I will make an answer.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much, it works with this: `s/(set NEX )([0-9.]+)/\1"\2"/` so sed substitute only the good line with float! 
without calling shell it is more easy :D
PS: I still don't understand your `\b` and `\+`

Comment: `\b` is a word boundary.  `\+` is `+` without the `-r` option for extended regex.

Comment: Just tested your code, it works as well and it's pretty more elegant. I did not know the use of enclosing in /: `/set NEX/{...}`. I need to learn more and more!
Thank you @stevesliva

Comment: `@KamilCuk, it returns: Illegal variable name.` [It _outputs_ "set NEX something"](https://replit.com/@kamilcukrowski/PricklyDeliciousReality#main.sh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/(set Nex)"([0-9]+)"/echo \1\\"$(echo "scale=2;\2\/2"|bc)\\"/e' file
```

For the `"`'s to be literal when echoed they must be escaped `\"`'s. Then the escapes must be escaped for the evaluation of the echo command by the `e` flag of the substitution `\\"`.

Answer (score 2):

Because the sed `e` command calls the shell, which interprets away quotes, it's easiest to simply replace the quotes in a subsequent sed command:

```
sed -r '/set NEX/{s/(set NEX ")([0-9.]+)(")/echo \1$(echo "scale=2;\2\/2" | bc)\3/e;s/\b[0-9.]+\b/"&"/}' testfile
```

Above adds `/set NEX/{}` around your command and then adds `s/\b[0-9.]+\b/"&"/` after it to enclose the float in double quotes.

Perl's maybe more straightforward here, but really not a lot:

```
perl -pe 's#\b([.0-9]+)\b#sprintf "%3.2f",$1/2.0#e if /set NEX/' testfile
```

Perl doesn't lose the double quotes, and is only modifying the float in the `s###e`